# Error converting image to byte for saving in database

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I have a win form with picture box and i want to store image to database so while converting image to byte to store in database I am getting the error.How to solve the error? Here is my code and I have also pointed out the line at which error (object reference not set to instance of object) occurs:

```
   public string ImageToBase64(Image image,
      System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);-------Error at this point----
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Convert Image to byte[]
        image.Save(ms, format);-------Error at this point----
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
          ..
     }
```

It should be:

```
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    }
```

RawFormat property of image returns the format of image

**EDIT 1**

You could also try to use ImageConverter class

```
 ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
 byte[] imageBytes= (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
```

**EDIT 2**

If you are saving bytearray in your database table then the columntype should be **VARBINARY**
Else if you are saving base64string it should be **VARCHAR(MAX)** or **VARCHAR(X)**

Comment: Still not working.Now its showing error at  image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat); this point.

Comment: While you are debugging, at any point before image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);, have you checked whether image is null?

Comment: Yeah before also in my code also it was showing error at the same line.How to remove that error??

Comment: I suspect it is other function which is calling this ImageToBase64(...) is culprit. If you could post the code which is calling this I might be able to help you.

Comment: conn.Sqlquery("Insert into Admission values('" + btnStudentName.Text + "','" +Convert.ToDateTime (dateTimePicker1.Text) + "','" + btnGender.Text + "','" + btnSemester.Text + "','" + btnSession.Text + "','" + btnHSSBoard.Text + "','" + ImageToBase64(pictureBox2.Image,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif) + "')");

Comment: That helped but now its showing ''String or binary data would be truncated'' at cmd.executenonquery() point.

Comment: The column in which you are inserting your bytearray should be "VARBINARY" in your SQL table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113494/discussion-between-pushpendra-and-sumit-bhattarai).